# node memcached compression issue

Tags: php, node.js, memcached

We are using memcached module along with node.js for storage of data . At that point of time, the data is set correctly in memcache. When we are trying to set some amount of huge data with the help of php, we are doing auto-compress and setting it in memcache. The same memcache key, when we are trying to access/get in node side using memcached module, it is throwing some junk characters along with the below error :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token x
at Object.parse (native)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/memcached/lib/memcached.js:318:26)
at EventEmitter.rawDataReceived (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/memcached/lib/memcached.js:484:50)
at EventEmitter.BufferBuffer (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/memcached/lib/memcached.js:440:12)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/memcached/lib/utils.js:68:17)
at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
at TCP.onread (net.js:347:14)
```

Please spare some time and try to help us. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of memcached and what is the MAXITEMSIZE of your memcached instance when encountering this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to access to the data from PHP first?

Comment: @Tomás Yeah we have tried to access the same memcache key-value from PHP . We will be checking if already memcache key exists or not and if it does , the new set of data is appended to the same memcacahe key in PHP .